# Pop View from NavigationStack Animation Issue in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationstack

I was wondering about the issue with the manual popping animation when changing the path in `NavigationStack`. When backing from **Subview1** to **RootView**, a **white** screen appears in the background during the popping process (it should be **yellow**).
**However**, the view pops up correctly when utilizing the '**back**' button on the navigation bar.

I attached a screenshot.
[image]

```
import SwiftUI

@Observable
class Router {
    static let shared = Router()
    var path : [String] = []
}

struct RootView: View {
    @Bindable var router = Router.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $router.path) {
            ZStack {
                Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack {
                    Text("RootView")
                    Button {
                        router.path.append("SubView1")
                    } label: {
                        Text("push SubView1")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { dest in
                SubView1(router: router)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView1: View {
    var router : Router
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Text("RootView")
                Button {
                    router.path.removeLast()
                } label: {
                    Text("back to RootView")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    RootView()
}
```

Comment: maybe **the bug** has been fixed in IOS-17.1, your code seems to work for me without
 a white screen appearing in the background during the popping process.
 Using MacOS 14.1, Xcode 15.1, tested on real ios17 devices (not Previews) and
 MacCatalyst. It could be different on older systems. I do get this in the console `changing items while animating can result in a corrupted navigation bar`

Comment: You right. It's a bug, I tried it on Xcode 15.1 Beta and iOS 17.1 Beta and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737284), this seems to be a SwiftUI bug.

If you are just navigating back *one* view, you can use the `dismiss` environment value instead:

```
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()
        VStack {
            Text("RootView")
            Button {
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("back to RootView")
            }
        }
    }
}
```